# Linux alternative to Azure Compute?

Tags: linux, cgroups

If I understand Microsoft Azure Compute correctly you just upload code into it and it runs it, throttling cpu, memory and networking bandwidth along the way so my code cant interfere with other peoples code or the hosting environment.

I want to host a service like this, where people would upload code and it would run and some framework would throttle cpu, memory and bandwidth.

I can see raw materials in Linux (cgroups, docker, tc) but is there something out there that combines it all together? And maybe tunes itself as it runs to increase/decrease throttles based on current load?

Comment: This question has been attacked for being too broad, but I got wonderful specific answers. I don't think this question was too broad. I ended up choosing to spin up individual processes that were controlled by linux cgroups, and using a nodejs code sandboxing solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft Azure is a public cloud offering both Infrastructure as a Service and Platform as a Service components. It sounds like the Platform as a Service (PaaS) aspects are what you are after — but note that you will need infrastructure of *some* sort to run this on.

There are two main open source projects which will allow you to build and run a PaaS of your own. They are OpenShift, from Red Hat*, and Cloud Foundry, from Pivotal. Both projects have quickstarts:

- [Try Cloud Foundry](https://pivotal.io/platform/pcf-tutorials/getting-started-with-pivotal-cloud-foundry-dev/introduction)
- [Getting Started With OpenShift (for Administrators)](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/getting_started/administrators.html#getting-started-administrators)

which can get you up and running on a demo system pretty quickly — but running a large-scale installation of either in production will take some expertise.

* disclaimer: I work for Red Hat, but not on OpenShift

Comment: Let's not forget OpenStack (in [Red Hat](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/linux-platforms/openstack-platform) or [RDO](https://www.rdoproject.org/) flavors) for your IaaS needs.